# Get notified when a variable changed

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Is there any way to get when a variable has been changed? And if so, how can I achieve this?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged?view=netframework-4.8

Comment: If you make the variable a property, you can have an event that is fired and things can subscribe to that event if they care if it has changed.

Answer (score 5):

The "official" way to do it, is `INotifyPropertyChanged`. E.g. it is used by UI's (Windows Forms, WPF) to automatically refresh controls, when the data object they are bound to updates.

```
public class MyClass : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    private void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }

    ...
}
```

Then you can implement properties like this

```
private string _name;
public string Name
{
    get { return _name; }
    set {
        if (value != _name) {
            _name = value;
            OnPropertyChanged(nameof(Name));
        }
    }
}
```

You can use it like this:

```
var myObj = new MyClass();
myObj.PropertyChanged += MyObj_PropertyChanged;

myObj.Name = "new name";

// Clean up (e.g. in a `Dispose()` method)
myObj.PropertyChanged -= MyObj_PropertyChanged;
```

Assuming this event handler:

```
// Will be called whenever a property of `MyClass` is updated.
private void MyObj_PropertyChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{
    // Example
    if (e.PropertyName == nameof(MyClass.Name)) {
        var myObj = (MyClass)sender;
        //TODO: do something.
    }
}
```

Comment: It is either change notification (like INotifyPropertyChanged) or polling. Of coruse, games are notorious pollers. So it might work better in the big sheme of things.

Comment: Yes, but polling requires that you either keep track of old and new values or that you have a changed-flag that you must reset after testing. See @hertelukas answer.

Comment: Or that you redraw every Frame from scratch, using fresh values from the gamestate. Something that games actually do. They are even more "notorious redrawers" then Web Applications. Generally you only start with Change Notification/caching once you start with GUI Imitation Libaries. No idea if one is part of Unity, however.

Answer (score 0):

Just check in the Update void. I would argue that this is the easiest way to achieve what you want in Unity.

```
var varToCheckIfChanged; //This is the variable you want to know if it is still the same
var tempVar; //This variable stores the original value, and every time the varToCheckIfChanged changed, you update it.

//Gets called on Start of the scene
void Start
{
     tempVar = varToCheckIfChanged;
}

//Gets called every frame
void Update
{
    if(varToCheckIfChanged != tempVar)
    {
        Debug.Log("Variable changed!"); //Debug when the variable is updated
        var tempVar = varToCheckIfChanged;
    }

}
```