# MVVM Binding in Unity3d or Bind properties to compenents (controls) in Unity3d

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, mvvm, async-await, data-binding

I am stuck in Binding Properties to Components (Controls like Text) in Unity using MVVM using INotifyPropertyChanged. I want to make changes in the Properties of ViewModel and those should reflect in my Scenes, just like we do in WPF, or Xamarin.Forms (MAUI).

Answer (score -1):

Thanks to @Olivier Jacot-Descombes [for this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60130101/8304176). Also upvote Olivier's answer if this helps.

Refer to this answer if you want to use **Async-Await** in Unity3d.

Using this method, we can also use async-await/Task based programming. Note that for animations and such stuff, we can achieve that using async-await and MVVM approach, but it would be better to use IEnumerators for animation stuff. Async-await would be better for dealing with IO, Network and other operations that requires us to wait before proceeding.

**Create a ViewModel Class**

```cs
public class MainSceneViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public string Title { get { return title; } set { title = value; OnPropertyChanged(nameof(Title)); } }
    string title;

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}
```

**In your Scene Script** (Attach to a Gameobject in Unity Inspector).

```cs
public class MainSceneScript : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Text SceneTitle; // Assign Text Component in Unity Inspector

    MainSceneViewModel mainSceneViewModel = new MainSceneViewModel();

    void Start()
    {
        mainSceneViewModel.PropertyChanged += ViewModelPropertyChanged;
        DelayedTitleChange();
    }

    async void DelayedTitleChange()
    {
        await Task.Delay(2000);
        mainSceneViewModel.Title = "This is the Main Scene";
    }

    // Will be called whenever a property of `MainSceneViewModel` is updated.
    void ViewModelPropertyChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.PropertyName == nameof(MainSceneViewModel.Title))
        {
            SceneTitle.text = mainSceneViewModel.Title;
        }
    }

    // Clean up
    void Dispose()
    {
        mainSceneViewModel.PropertyChanged -= ViewModelPropertyChanged;
    }
}
```

We can also use Model and notify property changed of that model.